# how to fetch product based on category from collection in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have 2 collections in firebase

```
CategoriesCollection:  [
{'Id':'1',Title:'Electronics',ParentId':''},
{'Id':'2','Title':'Clothe',ParentId':''},

{'Id':'3,'Title':'Mobile',ParentId':'1'},
{'Id':'4','Title':'Laptop',ParentId':'1'},
{'Id':'5','Title':'Shirts',ParentId':'2'},
{'Id':'6','Title':'Jeans',ParentId':'2'},

]
```

in above data, if ParentId is '' that means its ParentCategory and if it is not null than its a child category of it..like mobile is a child category of 1 (electronics)

and another collection is

```
ProductsCollection :[
{'id':'1', 'title':'S23 Ultra','CategoryId':'3'},
{'id':'2', 'title':'S24 Ultra','CategoryId':'3'},
{'id':'3', 'title':'Macbook Air','CategoryId':'4'},
{'id':'4', 'title':'Spykar shirt','CategoryId':'5'},
```

I have taken 4 buttons on screen to display its products

Mobile Laptop Jeans Shirts

i used this code for fetching related products

```
 Future<List<ProductModel>> categoryProducts(String categoryId) async {
    try {
      print(categoryId.toString());
      final list=await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Products').where('CategoryId',isEqualTo: categoryId).get();
      return list.docs.map((e) => ProductModel.fromSnapshot(e)).toList();
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

but now i have to take only two parent category and want to show all its products

Electronics Clothe
If i tap on electronics it should fetch all electronic products (mobile laptop)

how to code for collection in firebase

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to understand exactly what you're saying. But you want to display all the products related to that category when user selects one of the two categories Electronics or Clothes. To do this, first add another field to the `ProductsCollection` like this

```
ProductsCollection :[
{'id':'1', 'title':'S23 Ultra','CategoryId':'3','ParentId':'1'},
{'id':'2', 'title':'S24 Ultra','CategoryId':'3','ParentId':'1'},
{'id':'3', 'title':'Macbook Air','CategoryId':'4','ParentId':'1'},
{'id':'4', 'title':'Spykar shirt','CategoryId':'5','ParentId':'2'},
]
```

After that, create a new function, name it as `getAllParentProducts`and write the query like this inside this function.

```
 Future<List<ProductModel>> getAllParentProducts(String parentIdId) async {
    try {
      final list=await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Products').where('CategoryId',isEqualTo: parentIdId).get();
      return list.docs.map((e) => ProductModel.fromSnapshot(e)).toList();
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: No  u have not got the exact point.... factching products based on subcategory is easy but here i want to fetch products based on Parent Category

Comment: I don't know how your firestore data collections are.  So give a screenshot of firestore database